# Broken Slow cooker

Tags: food-safety, slow-cooking

I put 5 pounds of cold chicken in my crock pot at about 2 am. I had put lemon pepper and salt in with it. I got up this morning about 9:30 or 10 and discovered that it seems my slow cooker broke right after I put it on last night.  It smells fine and it is cold. I drained the water and washed it. Then put it in regular oven at 350. Is it safe to eat, if it smells and tastes ok?

Comment: Lavender, it's certainly not "safe". If your mom is willing to risk it, citing the "past without refrigerators", it is because "not safe" does not mean "will always make you sick". But it's like driving without a seat belt: the consequences can be very ugly and - yes - even lethal, at least in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'd throw it out. You have no idea what temperature it got to before the cooker broke, and how much time it sat in the danger zone.

Comment: Honestly it doesn't look like it cooked at all. My mom thinks it is okay because she grew up in the days of no refrigerators. But I am nervous about it.

Comment: @Lavender I would take Batman's advice here - IF IN DOUBT - THROW IT OUT!

Comment: @Lavender- the food supply has gotten much worse in the sense of strong bacteria and what not than in the old days. I'd def. throw it out.